# R: as.POSIXct returns NA

Tags: r

I am new on manipulating time in R. I am trying to turn a character a="201304021500" into POSIXct form using the following code:

```
#First I turn my charcter a into the format "2013/04/02 15:00" 

    annee=substr(a,1,4)
    mois=substr(a,5,6)
    jour=substr(a,7,8)
    heure=substr(a,9,10)
    a=paste(paste(annee,mois,jour,sep="/"),paste(heure,min,sep=":"),sep=" ")

#Then I use the as.POSIXct function (as follows) that unfortunately returns NA even though the date "2013/04/02 15:00" does not correspond to the time where #the DST was #changed in France (where I am working)

> as.POSIXct(a,format="%y/%m/%d %h:%m",tz="Europe/Paris")
[1] NA
```

How can I solve this problem ? Much appreciated !

Comment: `as.POSIXct("201304021500", format = '%Y%m%d%H%M')`

Comment: The format strings for as.POSIXct are case-sensitive. See ?strptime

Comment: `as.POSIXct("201304021500", format = '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M')`  the grammar components should be in there too...